# Laravel 5 fieldnames localization

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I have a system where I do translations in the same mysql record but in different fields.

**Example:**

```
title_en varchar(255)
title_de varchar(255)
title_fr varchar(255)
```

Of course there are also fields for content and seo like text_en, description_en etc.

What I do now to use the collection data in my blade template is this:

```
<h1>{{$page->{'title_' . App::getLocale()} }}</h1>
{!! $page->{'text_' . App::getLocale()} !!}
```

This works but is it the way to do it? What are best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't created page with translations in Laravel yet, but If I were you, I would create helper method for this and I would use something like that in my template:

```
<h1>{{ trtx('title') }}</h1>
{!! trtx('text') !!}
```

This way, you would have quite clean code in your template without hardcoding way of creating labels.

Just a sample implementation for this:

1. Create `app/helpers/functions.php` file:

   ```
   <?php

   function trtx($title, $locale = null)
   {
       if ($locale == null) {
           $locale = App::getLocale();
       }

       $trans = App::make('App\Services\Translator');

       return $trans->get($title . '_' . $locale);
   }
   ```
2. Create `app/Services/Translator.php` file:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Services;

   class Translator
   {
       public function get($text)
       {
           return "This is translated text for " . $text;
       }
   }
   ```
3. In `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in `register` function add:

   ```
       $this->app->singleton(
           'App\Services\Translator',
           'App\Services\Translator'
       );
   ```
4. In `composer.json` file add to `autoload` section loading your helper file, so it should look like this:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "database"
       ],
       "psr-4": {
           "App\\": "app/"
       },
     "files": [
       "app/Helpers/functions.php"
     ]
   },
   ```
5. Run in console `composer dump-autoload` and then run in console `php artisan clear-compiled`

Now it should work, if you put in your template for example:

```
{{ trtx('title') }} {{ trtx('title', 'fr') }}
```

you will get:

```
This is translated text for title_en This is translated text for title_fr
```

Of course now you should implement in `Translator` class the real way you get translation from database. Of course there is no point to use DB for translations all the time. You should cache table where you have translations because if you will run query each time you want to display translation it will be a waste of DB performance.

**EDIT**

I don't know if I understand you well, but probably you need to translate property for record you already have.

You could modify then `trtx` function a bit and use it this way:

```
{{ trtx($page, 'title') }} {{ trtx($page, 'title', 'fr') }}
```

(in this case you don't need to use `Translate` at all)

But if I use `Eloquent` (you haven't mentioned about it), you could do it also in a bit cleaner way. For your `Page` model you could add accessors for `title` and `text` properties (you must not have `title` or `text` columns in your table in database):

```
public function getTitleAtrtribute() 
{    
    return $this->{'title_'.\App::getLocale()};
}
public function getTextAtrtribute() 
{    
    return $this->{'text_'.\App::getLocale()};
}
```

and now in your `Blade` template you could use just:

```
<h1>{{ $page->title }}</h1>
{!! $page->text !!}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Especially the second edit. In my non framework days I did it the same way and I am very happy with this framework alternative :-)